# Access Current User Info from Angular App

Tags: angularjs

My application front-end is Angular SPA and backend is asp.net webapi. I have an issue to access user profile information from other part of the application:

When a user logs in, the profile information must be accessible from from all parts of the application. I put basic profile information in an object in the homeController which is the top controller, but when I access this object from child controller, I got the 'undefined' error when using one of the user profile properties, although I can get the whole object. When I was using console.log() to show the object, it is ok, all properties are there, but when console.log() to show one of the properties, the console shows either 'undefined'or noting shows up there. What did I do wrong?

My code:

In homeController (defined in  tab in index.html):

```
$scope.currentUser = authService.authentication;

console.log($scope.currentUser); // shows all properties ok.
```

In userDashController (defined in a part view accessed by route config in app.js):

```
$scope.fromCurrentUser = $scope.currentUser;

console.log($scope.fromCurrentUser); // show all properties ok

console.log($scope.fromCurrentUser.userAvatarImgUrl); // blank in the console

var comaId = $scope.currentUser.orgId;

console.log(comaId); // blank in the console
```

even I tried to inject authService, which set user profile when user logs in, and I got similar issue. Or I tried to use $rootScope, but still not working.

Not sure what I did it wrong (I am new to Angular, just a couple of months)

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever used $localStorage? I had issues with $rootScope while using firebase. But if you use $rootScope to keep the user authentication and use it to check if it is not null, it would find to hide other functionalities.